# Is onBootstrap() necessary in a Zend 2 module?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In the Zend 2 [skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication), the Application `module.php` contains a `onBootstrap()` function:

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }
...
```

Yet, this is not mentioned in the module creation [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/first-module.html).

Is it necessary to implement this function in each module? If yes, why? What is its purpose?

Comment: I've found it's usually good to have it in _one_ module and as long as you've done the default stuff above the other modules won't need it. Unfortunately I don't know the technicalities of it, but from experience I've found one is enough..

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-class.html
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.examples.html#bootstrapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: nope, it is not necessary.

The ModuleRouteListener is a feature to specify routes with the `__MODULE__` and `__CONTROLLER__` keys instead of the FQCN. If you don't need that feature (which will be in most cases of well developed apps), you don't need this route listener.

Furthermore, you only need to add this once, not for every module.

A last note, only put code in `onBootstrap()` which is very performant. It is executed on every request, so if you do a lot of work, this is slowing down your app significantly. So be aware of what you're doing there!